# Start-Job Using Credentials Fails With Error Username/Password Incorrect

Tags: powershell, credentials

I am working on a PowerShell script that needs to run a job as a different user due to different types of permissions used at my organization. When testing my script, I keep getting the error that the username or password is incorrect, even though I am certain the credentials I am using are correct.

My script right now gets the users credentials, and starts the job which just calls a second PS script. The second script is located in the same folder as the parent script. My code right now:

```
$PSScriptRoot
$scriptPath = $PSScriptRoot + "\sample2.ps1"

$cred = Get-Credential -Message "Please enter your non-admin account information"

$myJob = Start-Job -FilePath $scriptPath -Credential $cred

$myJob | Receive-Job -Keep

$myJob    #Output the job
```

I even tried the following which I found online, and using this format did not work either.

```
$username = Username
$password = Password

$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)
$Credentials = Get-Credential $cred
```

I am hoping that this process will allow the second script to be run off of the first script, since to complete the objective of my script, I must run the parent script as an admin account and the child script as a normal account, due to organizational differences in permissions. Instead, I continue to get the following error:

```
[localhost] An error occurred while starting the background process. Error reported: The user name or password is incorrect.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : -2147467259,PSSessionStateBroken
```

And get the following output from the job:

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
7      Job7            BackgroundJob   Failed        False           localhost            Write-Host "Hello Worl...
```

Any help with figuring out this credentials issue is much appreciated.

---

EDIT: My issue was that I was not using the `domain\username` format when entering my username in the credentials dialog. I also had to move the scripts to a drive that was accessible by both the non-admin and admin accounts, since they cannot access each other's C:\.

Comment: Are you giving the creds in the `domain\username` format?

Comment: See if you get the password back when you do `$cred.getnetworkcredential().password`

Comment: @RohinSidharth When I was testing yesterday, I was using the `domain\username` format and getting no results. However, I just tried again and it is now working using the `domain\username` format. I think this was also a combination issue with trying to access the C:\ for the admin account on the local machine from the non-admin account. I copied the files to a network drive that both accounts can access and now the job is running. Thanks for you help. I spent way too much time on this and apparently missed a couple simple things.

Comment: @RohinSidharth I also tried `$cred.getnetworkcredential().password` just to see, and I do get the password back. Is that what should be happening?

Comment: Yes, you should be getting the plaintext password back. that is how i make sure I get the creds correctly. Also, you are right about the C:\ drive. Nonadmin accounts have trouble accessing that location.